# Third Party DLLs in Azure Web API

Tags: azure, cybersource

CyberSource, our payment gateway, requires the registration of three DLLs for use by my e-commerce software. These DLLs must be registered using regsvr32. CyberSource ensures the safety and functionality of these DLLs.

Our e-commerce website's API is hosted in Azure Web API. I would like to know if there's a way to register these DLLs, if not, What are my options using Azure services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no such service as "Azure Web API".  Are you talking about Azure App Service?

Comment: You are right, I mean Azure App Service.

Comment: Hello. Azure support requests would be better served by asking Azure support.

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service is adding support for [Windows Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container), which you can customize.

Or since `regsvr32` implies that the .dll is a COM component, you might be able to use [Registration-Free COM Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/registration-free-com-interop)